# What is the right way to install a local module/library using npm v5

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have one local node module/library (named: *serviceLib-common*) which is used by multiple projects. Different projects ***package.json*** file is referring this dependency as file dependency

```
"dependencies": {
    "serviceLib-common":"file:../ serviceLibJs/serviceLib-common"
}
```

With npm version-3 I had no issues to install this local dependency in different environment. But recently I upgraded to Node-8 and npm version-5 cannot handle this. Npm v5 is not hoisting the dependency library and installing another *node_modules* under *serviceLib-common* directory. If I use **Yarn** (v1.0.2), Yarn can install the local dependency properly.

**Question:**

1. Is there any known issue with npm v5 to install local library? I
   tried with npm link but that does not help.
2. Is there any way to handle this using npm v5 (Probably using some flag? )

Comment: The spaces in the package name and the file path could be causing issues. Are they there in your `package.json` too, or are they just typos in your question?

Comment: Sorry for the typo... _package.json_ does not contain any space